# Appium IOS port #8100 is occupied

Tags: automation, appium

I started in the same Mac PC:

- 2 appium server in different port: 4723 and 4724
- xcodebuild for 2 different devices: device 1, device 2
  When I run the test script: device 1(port 4723) and device 2(port 4724) the error message is displayed as following:

  WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The port #8100 is occupied by an other process. You can either quit that process or select another free port.

Any idea or support is appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to parralel your tests. Or parallel test approaches may to help you. Start to explore this point from the next articles:

- https://appiumpro.com/editions/28-running-multiple-appium-tests-in-parallel
- https://kazucocoa.wordpress.com/2018/09/01/appiumpythonrun-tests-in-parallel-with-pytest/

The lastest link is tech diary of Appium developer. It helped in my questions.